# Filter elements by unique attribute values within a selection

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have this input:

```
<r>
<x>
<s>
<a u="1"/>
<a u="2"/>
</s>
<t>
<a u="1"/>
<a u="4"/>
</t>
</x>
<y>
<a u="4"/>
<a u="5"/>
<a u="4"/>
<a u="1"/>
</y>
</r>
```

I tried this xpath to filter all  elements by their @u attribute value

```
/r/x//a[not(@u=preceding-sibling::node()/@u)]
```

The expected output/result is:

```
Element='<a u="1"/>'
Element='<a u="2"/>'
Element='<a u="4"/>'
```

But I get:

```
Element='<a u="1"/>'
Element='<a u="2"/>'
Element='<a u="1"/>'
Element='<a u="4"/>'
```

As the preceding-sibling evaluates on the siblings within the parent structure, I need to tell to evaluate the expression on a given set of nodes instead, i.e. the result of `/r/x//a`.

Comment: Which version of XSLT and/or XPath do you use? XSLT 2 has `<xsl:for-each-group select="//a" group-by="@u"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:for-each>` to group `a` elements by the `u` attribute value and output the first element in each group. In XSLT 1 you could use Muenchian grouping or processor specific extensions.

Comment: Shouldn't `<a u="5"/>` also appear in the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming XSLT 2 or 3 (as for instance supported on the Java and .NET platform by Saxon 9) you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//a" group-by="@u">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and get

```
<a u="1"/>
<a u="2"/>
<a u="4"/>
<a u="5"/>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn59

Comment: I have replaced xsl:coy-of with xsl:sequence which also works, thanks.